# Datanode process not being activated

Tags: java, hadoop

On start-all.sh it showing that datanode starting but actually it is not activated.On jps command it is not in the list.Please help .It has taken a lot of time already.

Comment: it is showing during 'start-all.sh ',,   localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-Inspiron.out

Comment: Check this file `/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-Inspiron.log` and post the `ERROR` in it.